# Get data from an Html page into Python array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, urllib

I'm just trying to get some data from a webpage like this one:

```
[ . . . ]

<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 01</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 02</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 03</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 04</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 05</p>

[ . . . ]
```

I would like to have a python array like the following one:

```
myArrayWebPage = ["Lorem Ipsum 01","Lorem Ipsum 02","Lorem Ipsum 03","Lorem Ipsum 04","Lorem Ipsum 05"]
```

This is my python script:

```
import urllib.request

urlAddress = "http:// ... /" # my url address
getPage = urllib.request.urlopen(urlAddress)
outputPage = getPage.read()
print(outputPage)
```

How can I get the array from "outputPage"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do what you want:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> html = '''<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 01</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 02</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 03</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 04</p>
<p class="special-large">Lorem Ipsum 05</p>'''
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('<p class="special-large">([^<]+)</p>', html)
['Lorem Ipsum 01', 'Lorem Ipsum 02', 'Lorem Ipsum 03', 'Lorem Ipsum 04', 'Lorem Ipsum 05']
>>>
```

Please note that [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are typically not preferred for something like this. You should use a library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you what do you mean for "regular expressions"?

Comment: You can click on the term now, and a Wikipedia article will show up. Next time, try searching Google for a term you are not familiar with.

Comment: @JoeHunter Please take this opportunity to read the wildly entertaining answers on why regexes are insufficient to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags